# Cursing asuras is a Devata's privilege?

Tags: gods, asuras, curse

Cursing Asuras is a special priviledge of Devata or we human can help the Gods in this?

If yes where and which passage represents a valid reference ?

Comment: What is your basic idea of human assisting devas in cursing asuras? Do you mean by complaining  to them ? Except some  few  we humans don't have the power  to give boons and curses directly to asuras ,so helping devas in cursing  is somewhat outside of our domain.